# Launching GWT project from Eclipse using built repo output SDK responds with 404

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, open-source

I am taking a software engineering university course and my team has chosen to tackle the Google Web Toolkit open source project for a class project involving a bug fox or feature addition. I have my SVN set up and checked out the repositories for trunk and tools, then I downloaded Eclipse and added the Google Plugin for it, along with the GWT Developer Plugin Chrome extension.

When I create a new sample project pointing to the SDK that came with the Eclipse plugin, and then run it in Chrome, it works fine. However, if I make a new project with the SDK pointed to the output lib folder in my local SVN (C:\Repos\GWT\trunk\build\lib), the local server responds with a 404 error. Here are the response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Server: Development/1.0
Date: Thu, 10 Jan 2013 08:47:40 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 83
```

I can't figure out what's causing this, can anybody help?

Comment: You need to update your question explaining what code snippet led to the 404 error. RPC, JSON, HTML access ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a custom-built GWT SDK, then either point to its `build/staging/gwt-*`, or just make sure you have the gwt-dev and gwt-user projects in your Eclipse workspace and then use https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/gwt_contrib_sdks